# create application setting inside application

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, application-settings, settings.bundle

I want to Get all my Application Setting transfer from **Setting** to Application inside .

Like I have settings like this in my Setting 
[image]

And I want to handle it from my application. The main problme is that when i need to change my setting I need to minimize of kill my application to save its changes . So Do i want to put it inside my Application on click of one tabbar button . So I can change it any time from inside my application .

How do I put all this in my custom view which i have created inside my application .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

If I have not misunderstood, then I think your requirement is like this:

[How do I open the Settings application from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application)

Answer (score 0):

Think you cannot access(get/set saved items in) Settings.app from your application if you are using iOS5.1 
Please see [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664315/access-settings-app-in-ios) for reference.