# How to launch myapplication settings tab in settings app from my application in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there any way to open myapplication settings tab directly from my application like what we will use to open twitter settings

```
([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]]).
```

Answer (score 1):

By showing the **Facebook** or **Twitter** composer with the standard iOS Social Framework, will present us an AlertView with an option to go directly to FB or Twitter Settings for the users **if** the accounts are not setup. So this will be helpful when you want to your user to login to them via the **Settings** app, if they haven't done so.

Have tested this with iOS 6 in iPad with both FB and Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the canSendTweet method to check before you tweet, just present the ViewController.  Should work for the Social framework as well, if you are working with iOS6.  Example below.

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];

//If the user doesn't have twitter enabled then an alertview will pop up giving them to option to go straight to settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just show the composer. If no FB Account is available, it will show an AlertView to go to Settings. Works in iOS 8

```
var controller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
controller.setInitialText("My Post")
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
```

I don't believe that opening the settings for any app other than your own (including the Twitter and Facebook configuration page) is supported.