# Open Settings.app When Button is Tapped in UIAlertView on iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, settings, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Is there a way to direct the user to the Settings.app whenever I show a `UIAlertView` prompt? This prompt alerts the user that his location services is turned off and I want the user to open the Settings.app when he taps the button inside my `UIAlertView`.

UPDATE: I'm looking for a similar code stated here:

[How to launch myapplication settings tab in settings app from my application in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909615/how-to-launch-myapplication-settings-tab-in-settings-app-from-my-application-in/13195833#13195833)

Comment: I think from `iOS 5.1`, we can't redirected to Default to ** some ** Settings. `iOS 5.0` or before you can do so.... So, I think your answer is NO.

Comment: check This [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092142/ios-uialertview-button-to-go-to-setting-app) May Be helpful for you ..thanks :)

Comment: @iPatel It doesn't work at all...:)

Comment: It's not working on iOS 5.1 and up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### iOS 8 and iOS 9

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

<strike>There is no way to do this.</strike>

Because till now (11th Jan 2013) there is no **url scheme** available for settings app.

#### iOS 6

You can't do this on iOS 6.

#### iOS 5 and below (< iOS 5.1)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
```

Please refer this answer for more info [Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone)

Comment: I think this facility was available with `iOS 5.0` and earlier, right? After that, it is of no use.

Comment: @Goti: Yes you are right :)