# UIAlertView to Settings and to Disable Airplane mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uialertview

There's already been a question about this, but I'm certain we're missing something: [Open Settings.app When Button is Tapped in UIAlertView on iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275314/open-settings-app-when-button-is-tapped-in-uialertview-on-iphone-sdk)

The generally accepted theory is that using alert view to send to the settings has been redacted. However, the One Note app has it embedded. Also, (in reverse) if you open your text message 'app' when in airplane mode you can automatically disable airplane mode.

How is this done?

UIAlertView? Something else?

**EDIT**

Chrome, Pandora, and One Note (so far, in my research) all successfully implement this feature. How?

Comment: There is no API that allows a 3rd party app to launch the Settings app. Any alert that appears to do so is coming from the OS, not the app.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what the research I have found says. However, does this mean that some apps have established a special relationship with Apple to allow them to make requests to the OS that is not publicly available? If you have the One Note app by Microsoft, this feature is implemented and working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to do this. There is no public URL scheme to open the Settings app.

If the system wide alert view is triggered, it may open Settings app. But you can't trigger that yourself.

Comment: Then how does the One Note app do it?