# Connect inappsettings to a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an app where i need to create own app settings. These settings needs to be shown in a viewcontroller. i've created an settings.bundle how can i associate this with a viewcontroller? i've tried to follow different tutorials, but all cases they are being show under the iphone settings. if this is not possible how can i then achieve this?

Comment: Only available since iOS 8. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229422/accessing-the-settings-app-from-your-app-in-ios-8

Comment: Well but what about big apps like tinder, snapchat and so on? do they create their own settings from a UITableView?

Comment: Well exactly. And if they have settings both in the iphone settings app and inside their app, it's duplicated...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have implemented working tutorial code correctly, you will need to **delete** your app and **reinstall** it in order to access data from the settings bundle. Hope this helps!

Note: This is necessary if settings.bundle has *just* been added to your target.

Comment: This is false, the settings bundle is accessible at any time