# Deep link in to iOS Settings' Notifications page?

Tags: ios, nsurl, deep-linking

I know that I can [deep link into the](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-taking-the-user-to-settings/) [Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24229422/35690) on iOS via `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`. However, this takes me to a page such as this:

[image]

Now if I want the user to enable notifications, they have to find Notifications in the list and then enable it. Is there a way to instead directly link them to the Notifications page? (i.e. Going to the same exact page as though they had tapped notifications in the screenshot above.)

If not, is there a way to take them to the global notifications iOS Settings page? (See screenshot below for an example)

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there is no way to go to any other page in the Settings app from a third party app. Using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` is the only option available.

Comment: Is this still the case as of iOS 10?

Comment: @rmaddy, the TrueCaller app deep links into the Phone section of Settings (on iOS 11), so it is possible. Though perhaps not sanctioned by Apple?

Comment: Check those schemes https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560

Answer (score 1):

Deep linking into the Push Notification settings of an App is possible starting with iOS 15.4 with `UIApplicationOpenNotificationSettingsURLString` (deprecated).

It was replaced with `UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString` in iOS 16.

All versions prior to iOS 15.4 can only deep link into the general settings of the app with `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`.