# App-Prefs: root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID Not working on iOS 11 Swift 4

Tags: ios, notifications, ios11, swift4

I'm trying to use:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But it's just sending me to the Settings app, not to the Notification tab.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024467/5086202) without luck.

Any solution?

Comment: Looks like you were using undocumented API and it stoped to work. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33003961/3050403

Comment: Not working too. https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560 didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will Reject your app submission. Because this is the private api. Use the below function in the below. ref: [How do I open phone settings when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked)

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
    return
}

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
         print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
    })
}
```