# From which version of iOS does the system has permission control?

Tags: ios, mobile, permissions

Which version of iOS first had the feature of managing app's permissions?

Comment: Are you talking about an app being able to deep link to their settings in the Settings app?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I expressed badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature was new in iOS 8 so any device running iOS 8+ is able to do that. Here's more info: [Accessing the Settings app from your app in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229422/accessing-the-settings-app-from-your-app-in-ios-8)