# Open setting area in IOS 5.1

Tags: iphone

how can i open setting area of iphone in objective c iphone app in ios 5.1?

In IOS 5.0, It's working fine but in IOS 5.1 It is not working.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]];
```

Please provide me a link of apple development center, which ensure me it is not working in IOS 5.1.

Comment: Apple disabled this in iOS 5.1.

Comment: Apple did not supply any information about opening the settings app in the SDk in the first place. Thus we will not be able to provide you with a link to Apple Development center wich will ensute you that it does not work on iOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open prefrences/settings with iOS 5.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-prefrences-settings-with-ios-5-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [How to open preferences/settings with iOS 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-prefrences-settings-with-ios-5-1)

Apple removed this feature in iOS 5.1. Doesn't look like there's a workaround. Sorry!

Comment: Is there any other way to ON WI-fi pragmatically?