# Open Settings → Wifi from alert button action in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to open Settings from my app's alertView button action with following URL Scheme.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]];
```

It's working fine for iOS 5.0 but not for 5.1 and above.

Any alternate way to implement this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open preferences/settings with iOS 5.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-preferences-settings-with-ios-5-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply no. This URL scheme has been disabled by Apple in SDK 5.1. Its not possible without Jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is no more supported in iOS 5.1 and above. No direct way to do this.