# Alternative to open preference from an iOS 5.1 app like Twitter

Tags: email, ios5, settings

I have been trying to add a button in my app like Twitter do in iOS 5.1

[image]

to send user to mail setting when he has not a email account configured. I don´t know if Twitter can do this because it is a framework in iOS.

Older solutions like:

[openURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-preferences-settings-with-ios-5-1)

doesn´t work.

What method is valid to do this on iOS 5.1?

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed in new version of iOS (6.0.1)!