# How to open settings from our app in ios5.1?

Tags: iphone, ipad, settings

I want to open settings from my application in ios 5.1, but I didn't find any source to open settings.Can anybody please guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-preferences-settings-with-ios-5-1"

Comment: That is not working fine for ios 5.1