# How to open settings from my iPad application (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, hyperlink, settings

I've tried using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @ "prefs: root = General & path = Network"]];
```

And options trading all you see here:

[examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

But I can not make it work.

Comment: As far as iOS 6 and 7, this can not be done. With iOS 8, it can be done using the following code: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apple no longer allows developers to open the Settings application from within their apps (iOS 5.1 and later).

***EDIT***

According to @Mike's comment below, this can be done in iOS 8+

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Using this prior to iOS 8 will result in a crash, however.

Comment: This is incorrect, because in iOS 8 this is allowed.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]; is how it is done, although just in case anyone sees this, this will crash if you try to run it in iOS 7 as the const doesn't exist.

Comment: how would you go back to the app? Can you add a callback?

Comment: It is now supported on iOS 9. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399893/open-phone-settings-programmatically-in-ios9

Comment: This won't open the Settings homepage. Instead, it will open the app settings page (it's the page where users can see/opt-out permissions like GPS, Camera access, notifications etc.)