# If GPS is disabled, how to redirect user to Privacy to turn on Location Access?

Tags: ios, cordova, gps, geolocation

I was able to catch if the GPS is disabled using Geolocation Plugin of Phonegap 3.6.3. Is there a way how to display this image below? Or is it customized dialog?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDIgF.png]

Also, on other apps, once the Settings button is clicked, they are redirected to this page.

[image]

Can anyone here help me how to achieve this? I was searching for resources but I cant find anything that will help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25773728/646998

Comment: @Christopher i tried earlier to copy the code but nothing happened. I think the code is in xcode build or it can be run in phonegap?

Comment: You can display an alert but you can no longer have a button to launch the settings.  That ability was removed in iOS 6

Comment: @Paulw11 So if this is the case, how could Facebook or Tinder and other ios apps that uses geolocation do this?

Comment: That dialog is shown automatically by iOS when your app tries to access location services but it is turned off.

Comment: The value of this key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` should be a string, not an array - it is the message that gets displayed in the alert.  iOS will only display this alert the first time an app requests access while location services are off - if the user presses cancel they are never prompted again for that app. Try deleting and re-installing your app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63824/discussion-between-zynder-and-paulw11).