# iOS Location Services Alert - What is the delay between showing it?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, alert, cllocationmanager

Just a quick question here.

I am displaying the the alert for the user to allow the app to access location data, and I have this triggered from a switch.

When the user turns the switch on, the alert will be displayed.

If the user clicks disallow, is there a time restriction that Apple has before you can show that alert again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer is "no" but I suspect what you really want to know is how to show it again if the user has disallowed it. Correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prompt user to turn on Location Services...again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998465/how-to-prompt-user-to-turn-on-location-services-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user chooses not to give your app permission to access their location data, the user will not be able to grant your app that permission from within your app. Instead, the user must enter the Settings app and grant the permission from there. This is to prevent the app from bombarding the user with requests to use location data.